# Puppet - while installing puppet dashboard, a rubygems(rake) dependency is blocking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, puppet, puppet-enterprise

I am trying to install puppet-dashboard on a linux machine (EL 6). But this installation is blocked by a dependency on rubygems(rake). But i have this already installed on my machine.

please find the below details which might be helpful for showing me the way forward.

```
[admin@server ~]$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [x86_64-linux]
[admin@server ~]$ gem list
YAML safe loading is not available. Please upgrade psych to a version that supports safe loading (>= 2.0).

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (default: 1.16.1)
json (1.5.5)
rake (10.5.0)
```

below is what i see when i try to install puppet-dashboard

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package puppet-dashboard.noarch 0:1.2.23-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(rake) for package: puppet-dashboard-1.2.23-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: ruby-mysql for package: puppet-dashboard-1.2.23-1.el6.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package puppet-dashboard.noarch 0:1.2.23-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(rake) for package: puppet-dashboard-1.2.23-1.el6.noarch
---> Package ruby-mysql.x86_64 0:2.8.2-1.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: puppet-dashboard-1.2.23-1.el6.noarch (puppetlabs-products)
           Requires: rubygem(rake)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: Rake in installed via `gem` and `puppet-dashboard` is being installed via the package manager. these are two separate loading paths.

Comment: hi Matt, thanks for showing interest here. so you are saying that i have to install Rake using the package manager so that the Puppet-dashboard will get its dependency resolved ?

Comment: Yes, or install `puppet-dashboard` with gem. The package manager seems to be better choice in your situation though. Alternatively, you can somehow instruct Ruby to find `rake` while installing with the package manager, but this kind of environment manipulation is beyond what I can help with over SO. Really this is an environment issue and my suggestion may not even be the right direction.

Comment: hi Matt, i have made some searches on google again to check how to install rake using Yum, but could not find any successful solution, in this link - https://jsdom.wordpress.com/2011/08/06/install-ruby-and-rake-on-rhel-6/

it says to download a tarball inside which a install-db file can be used to install rake, but i could not find this install-rb file inside the downloaded tarball

Comment: Yeah sorry, this is going to need to be solved by fixing your environment for Ruby/yum interaction dependency pathing. I have no idea how to start with that, since I do not mix the two myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this and now I am feeling silly to post this question since the answer to it is so simple.

I just went to this link https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=rubygem-rake and downloaded the Rake rpm, installed. and bam !! the puppet-Dashboard solves its dependency with the rake!